# Ajax response issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a 2 jsp files as shown below.

I have a parent jsp page where there are two options in the select drop down box.

And i have another jsp which displays select boxes inside a table.

I want the dispTable.jsp's output as an ajax response in the page parent.jsp if the user selects the option "one" in the drop down select box.

The problem i am facing is the parent.jsp page displays the content of the dispTable.jsp in the parent.jsp page as ajax response but the '>>' and '<<' buttons do not work.

But if i try to execute the dispTable.jsp by directly providing the parameter and value in the url the select tables and the buttons just work perfectly.

How is that the same output is not working for parent.jsp.

For the below url the output is working perfectly.
http://student.details.com:8080/stud/dispTable.jsp?count=one

```
 **parent.jsp**
<html>
      <head>  
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
      var xmlHttp  
      var xmlHttp
      function showEmp(str){
      if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
      xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else if (window.ActiveXObject){
      xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      if (xmlHttp==null){
      alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
      return;
      } 
      var url="dispTable.jsp";
      url +="?count=" +str;
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
      xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
      }

      function stateChange(){   
      if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
      document.getElementById("emp").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText   
      }   
      }
      </script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {

$('#add').click(function() {


                            return !($('#list1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#list2') && ($('#list2:last-child').selected="selected"));

                });

                $('#remove').click(function() {

                                return !$('#list2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#list1');


                });
});
var arrOldValues;
function FillListValues(CONTROL) 
{

    var intNewPos;
    var arrNewValues = GetSelectValues(CONTROL);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrNewValues.length; i++) {
        if (arrNewValues[i] == 1) {
            intNewPos = i;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arrOldValues.length; i++) {
        if (arrOldValues[i] == 1 && i != intNewPos) {
            CONTROL.options[i].selected = true;
        } else if (arrOldValues[i] == 0 && i != intNewPos) {
            CONTROL.options[i].selected = false;
        }
        if (arrOldValues[intNewPos] == 1) {
            CONTROL.options[intNewPos].selected = false;
        } else {
            CONTROL.options[intNewPos].selected = true;
        }
    }
}

function GetSelectValues(CONTROL) 
{
    var strTemp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < CONTROL.length; i++) {
        if (CONTROL.options[i].selected == true) {
            strTemp.push(1);
        } else {
            strTemp.push(0);
        }
    }
return strTemp;


}
function GetCurrentListValues(CONTROL) 
{
    arrOldValues = GetSelectValues(CONTROL);
}
</script>
      </head>  
      <body>  
<select name = "ratingsClient" style="width: 150px" id="ratingsClient" onchange="showEmp(this.value)">
<option value="aaa">aaa</option>
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
</select>
<br>  
      <div id="emp">  
      <table name="emp" >  

      </table>  
      </div> 
</body>
</html>


**dispTable.jsp**
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {

$('#add').click(function() {


                            return !($('#list1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#list2') && ($('#list2:last-child').selected="selected"));

                });

                $('#remove').click(function() {

                                return !$('#list2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#list1');


                });
});
var arrOldValues;
function FillListValues(CONTROL) 
{

    var intNewPos;
    var arrNewValues = GetSelectValues(CONTROL);
    for (var i = 0; i < arrNewValues.length; i++) {
        if (arrNewValues[i] == 1) {
            intNewPos = i;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arrOldValues.length; i++) {
        if (arrOldValues[i] == 1 && i != intNewPos) {
            CONTROL.options[i].selected = true;
        } else if (arrOldValues[i] == 0 && i != intNewPos) {
            CONTROL.options[i].selected = false;
        }
        if (arrOldValues[intNewPos] == 1) {
            CONTROL.options[intNewPos].selected = false;
        } else {
            CONTROL.options[intNewPos].selected = true;
        }
    }
}

function GetSelectValues(CONTROL) 
{
    var strTemp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < CONTROL.length; i++) {
        if (CONTROL.options[i].selected == true) {
            strTemp.push(1);
        } else {
            strTemp.push(0);
        }
    }
return strTemp;


}
function GetCurrentListValues(CONTROL) 
{
    arrOldValues = GetSelectValues(CONTROL);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="select.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<%
String name=request.getParameter("count");
if(name.equals("one"))
{
String buffer1="<table>";
buffer1=buffer1+"<tr>";
buffer1=buffer1+"<td>";
buffer1=buffer1+"<SELECT class=\"select\" NAME=\"list1\" onMouseDown=\"GetCurrentListValues(this);\" id=\"list1\" MULTIPLE SIZE=10 style=\"width:150px;\" onClick=\"FillListValues(this)\">";

                                        buffer1=buffer1+"<option value=\"co_group\">Compnay Description</option>";
                                        buffer1=buffer1+"<option value=\"pe_rev_name\">Contact Name</option>";
                                        buffer1=buffer1+"<option value=\"co_tel_work\">Telephone</option>";
                    buffer1=buffer1+"<option value=\"action_flag\">Company Address</option>";
                                        buffer1=buffer1+"<option value=\"co_group\">Compnay Description</option>";
                                        buffer1=buffer1+"<option value=\"pe_rev_name\">Contact Name</option>";
                                        buffer1=buffer1+"<option value=\"co_tel_work\">Telephone</option>";
                                        buffer1=buffer1+"<option value=\"pe_position\">Contact Position</option>";
                                        buffer1=buffer1+"<option value=\"pe_tel_work\">Contact Telephone</option>";
                                        buffer1=buffer1+"<option value=\"ref_no\">ISBN</option>";
                                                                buffer1=buffer1+"</SELECT>";
                                                                buffer1=buffer1+"</td>";
                                                                buffer1=buffer1+"<td>";

          buffer1=buffer1+"<INPUT TYPE=\"button\" NAME=\"right\" VALUE=\"&gt;&gt;\" id=\"add\" style=\"width:40px;\"><BR><BR>";
          buffer1=buffer1+"<INPUT TYPE=\"button\" NAME=\"left\" VALUE=\"&lt;&lt;\" id=\"remove\" style=\"width:40px;\"><BR><BR>";


                                                                buffer1=buffer1+"</td>";
                                                                buffer1=buffer1+"<td>";

buffer1=buffer1+"<SELECT NAME=\"list2\" onMouseDown=\"GetCurrentListValues(this);\" id=\"list2\" MULTIPLE SIZE=10  style=\"width:150px;\" onClick=\"FillListValues(this)\">";

                                                                    buffer1=buffer1+"</SELECT></td></tr>";
                                    buffer1=buffer1+"</table>";
                                    response.getWriter().println(buffer1); 
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to write short and concise code and test it at your end.

Comment: I need a minimum of this feature to work for my actual code.This is just a sample if it works will help the actual implementation.If you could point at what's wrong it could be very helpful.Can this code be tested in your machine.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you fiddling with raw `XMLHttpRequest` while you're already using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You have the same Javascript both in "parent" and in "dispTable" - you need to remove it from one of them.

see functions like `GetSelectValues(CONTROL)` and `FillListValues(CONTROL)`.

By the way - you don't need to use the "buffer" you can write something like this

....

Please note I used `"one".equals(name)` and not `name.equals("one")` as it also handles null cases. 
please let me know if there's anything else you need that I might have missed.

Here is my working code (I had remove the if 'one'.equals condition on my workspace since it does not support JSP)

the parent file looks like this :

```
<html>
      <head>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function showEmp(str){
          $("#emp").load("dispTable.jsp");
      }
      </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

      </head>
      <body>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          function add()
          {
               return !($('#list1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#list2') && ($('#list2:last-child').selected="selected"));
          }
          function remove()
          {
               return !$('#list2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#list1');
          }
</script>

<select name = "ratingsClient" style="width: 150px" id="ratingsClient" onchange="showEmp(this.value)">
<option value="aaa">aaa</option>
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
</select>
<br>
      <div id="emp">
      <table name="emp" >

      </table>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the "dispTable" file looks like this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<SELECT class="select" NAME="list1" id="list1" MULTIPLE SIZE=10 style="width:150px;">;
    <option value="co_group">Compnay Description</option>
    <option value="pe_rev_name">Contact Name</option>
    <option value="co_tel_work">Telephone</option>
    <option value="action_flag">Company Address</option>
    <option value="co_group">Compnay Description</option>
    <option value="pe_rev_name">Contact Name</option>
    <option value="co_tel_work">Telephone</option>
    <option value="pe_position">Contact Position</option>
    <option value="pe_tel_work">Contact Telephone</option>
    <option value="ref_no">ISBN</option>
</SELECT>
</td>
    <td>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="right" VALUE="&gt;&gt;" id="add" onclick="add()" style="width:40px;"><BR><BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="left" VALUE="&lt;&lt;" id="remove" onclick="remove()" style="width:40px;"><BR><BR>
    </td>
    <td>
        <SELECT NAME="list2" id="list2" MULTIPLE SIZE=10 style="width:150px;">
        </SELECT>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

EDIT : extending the response to show how to send "value" of select box in the ajax request using "GET" method instead of "LOAD"

```
function showEmp(str){
    $.get("dispTable.jsp",{"count":str},function(result){$("#emp").html(result)})
}
```

Comment: I pasted the code in both the jsp files as it was not working before with or without them.Now even after removing in dispTable.jsp the code is not working.Can you check if the code is running in your system.It sounded like you were referring to corrected code o dont see the code you posted.

Comment: I added my code - I had to remove the JSP snippet - but since this is more a javascript/ajax/jquery question, I don't think it should bother you.

Comment: I tried this and i wanted the response though ajax only as i need to pass an employee name and get his details in the pagea as an ajax response if the employee exists.This was just a sample to get the ball rolling which is not working.

Comment: the "dispTable" is loaded with ajax.

Comment: In this method how do i pass values from parent to dispTable.Before i was able to pass/retreive values using request parameter.And in dispTable i need to query database populate the table and then return the result as ajax response.

Comment: In the code I pasted I used the jquery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function which supports passing data - but if data is provided it uses "POST" instead of "GET". I recommend you use the [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method. should look something like `$.get('dispTable.jsp',{dataKey:dataValue},function(result){$("#emp").html(result)})`

Comment: Could you show how do i modify the syntax of showEmp() function and pass the value of the selected option in the drop down box to dispTable.jsp.I am not familiar with this type of syntax.Please help...

Comment: added an example as you requested. You can also see [my wiki on the subject](http://wiki.mograbi.info/javascript/jquery/how-to-use-the-get-method).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The buttons are working now to shift values but where do i paste the java script functions FillListValues(), GetSelectValues() and  GetCurrentListValues() so that they have the same effect as before while selecting values.